# .htaccess rewrite file not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I know that there are a lot of questions about this topic here, but I am unable to get my `.htaccess` to work.

### Expected

All traffic should be redirected to `/index.php` using RewriteEngine

### Result:

Using the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [NC,QSA,R]
```

I get the following error (using `http://localhost/foo`, should be redirected to: `http://localhost/index.php`:

`The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.`

### Server/Config

Output from `ls` in `/var/www/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data root 4096 May 30 16:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root     root 4096 May 30 16:57 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root   92 May 30 17:34 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data root    4 May 30 16:50 index.php
```

The configuration for the path:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where is your `DocumentRoot`? Is it /var/www or somewhere else?

Comment: I've not changed the default configuration, but by default (if there is no index file) It shows the content of `/var/www/html/`. Should I post the whole config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following with absolute target path:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [R,L]
```

Comment: This looks good, but I get the error from both firefox and chrome, that my page is redirecting to much (`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`)

Comment: It works now with your rule, there was a problem with my confiuration too, thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you seem to have access to the server configuration, there's no need to use an `.htaccess` file. Just add the rewrite directives inside your `Directory` directive.

The problem with your rewrite rules seem to be the difference between the `Directory` and .htaccess being `/var/www`, but your document root is `/var/www/html`. In order to find `/index.php` (note the leading slash), it must be located in the document root, `/var/www/html` and not in `/var/www`.